# How can we use d3.js in a ruby on rails document?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js

I have been trying to display a graph in my site. I currently just see axis so i'm not sure if I am messing up the relationship between d3.js and ruby on rails.

What I have currently is:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var dataset = gon.data.map(function(datapoint) {
    datapoint.date = Date.parse(datapoint.date);
    return datapoint;
  });

  var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    console.log(d.date)
    return d.date;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.weight;
  })
  .interpolate("linear");

  var vis = d3.select("#visualization"),
  WIDTH = 600,
  HEIGHT = 500,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]),
  yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,250]),

  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale);

  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);

  vis.append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', lineGen(dataset))
    .attr('stroke', 'green')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2);
});
```

but all I see are the axis of my graph.

I have in my users controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @weights = Weight.where(user_id: @user.id)
  start_date = Date.parse(@weights.order("created_at").first.date)
  end_date = Date.parse(@weights.order("created_at").last.date)
  @graph_weight_date = Array.new
  (start_date..end_date).each do |day|
    if defined?  @weights.where(date: day.to_s).first.weight
       @graph_weight_date << { :date => day, :weight => @weights.where(date: day.to_s).first.weight}
    else
      @graph_weight_date << { :date => day, :weight => nil}
    end
  end
  gon.data = @graph_weight_date
end
```

and in my users/show.html.erb

```
<svg id ="visualization" width="600" height="500"></svg>
```

I'm not sure how to make the data correctly be pulled from ruby into d3.js

Comment: man what you do `d3` only need json object to display graph

Comment: @uzaif could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: http://www.overfitted.com/blog/?p=302 this post man

Answer (score 1):

D3 support isn't built into rails. When you load D3 into your page, all you are doing is sending the library with the Javascript. On the user's browser, they have access to whatever content you load onto the page (or fetch using AJAX).

So if you are using Rails to populate the page, your DOM will have some HTML elements that contain the data you're going to use in D3.

In your D3 script, it shouldn't really make much of a difference where the data comes from as long as it's on the page.

Maybe you could try testing your D3 code without relying on Rails. Write a static HTML page and include whatever data you need to test your D3 code. Then debug the D3. After making your code work, you can replace your test data with live data from Rails.